# My Sequelize Query always make wrong query when I use findById(req.params.id)

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

So I'm trying to make an update query, but every time I run the query it's always getting the wrong find id.
This is the first time I'm getting error like this.
In my other project this never happens

```
QuestionController.updateQuestionAnswer = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const questionAnswer = await QuestionAnswer.findById(req.params.id)
        console.log(questionAnswer)
        res.status(200).send({
            status_code: 200,
            questionAnswer,
            message: 'Updated'
        })
    } catch(error) {
        console.log(error)
        return res.status(500).send({ status_code: 500, message: error })
    }
}
```

[image: Wrong Find By Id Where answer_id]

Comment: What is wrong in the query? What you expect?

Comment: `req.params.id` is `4` actually?

Comment: is that PUT request .. and answer_id is your primary key and did you check your db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change it to a WHERE clause, because `FindById` can only be used if you have one key (For example a normal `Id`) and not if there are multiple keys (Answer_Id and Question_id) or no key.

```
const questionAnswer = await QuestionAnswer.where(x => x.question_id == req.params.id)
```